# How to wait until one function completes and loops

Tags: javascript, forms, prompt, alertify

This is part of my code :

```
document.querySelector("#edit_<?= $row["item_id"]; ?>").addEventListener("submit", function(a){
    if(!completed){
        a.preventDefault();
    }else{
        return true;
    }

    if((function(){
        alertify.prompt("New Amount of Item : ", function(e, str){
            if(e){
                document.querySelector("#edit_<?= $row["item_id"]; ?> input[name=\"item_amount\"]").value = str;
                var completed = true;
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        })
    )() == true){
        document.querySelector("#edit_<?= $row["item_id"]; ?>").submit();
    }
});
```

Where `<? $row["item_id"]; ?>` will return something (ignore it, it isn't the real problem)

But the problem is that I need to wait until `alertify.prompt()` gets `str` and then put it to

```
document.querySelector("#edit_<?= $row["item_id"]; ?> input[name=\"item_amount\"")
```

(Sorry for this messy code)

What can I do to solve this?

P.S. Better not use a jQuery solution if possible because it is already given. Use a Javascript-Only solution please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second `if` condition and just use the `alertify` callback function:

```
// define the completed variable outside the callbacks
var completed = false;
document.querySelector("#edit_<?= $row["item_id"]; ?>").addEventListener("submit", function(a){
    if(!completed){
        a.preventDefault();
    }else{
        return true;
    }
    alertify.prompt("New Amount of Item : ", function(e, str){
        if(e){
            document.querySelector("#edit_<?= $row["item_id"]; ?> input[name=\"item_amount\"]").value = str;
            //no var before completed, because then it would be local to this callback function
            completed = true;
            // here instead returning "true" do what you wanted to do if true
            document.querySelector("#edit_<?= $row["item_id"]; ?>").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The prompt function receives a callback function which will be executed after the text is 
 received. You can continue your logic in there

`alertify.prompt("Message", function (e, str) {
    // str is the input text
    if (e) {
        // user clicked "ok"
    } else {
        // user clicked "cancel"
    }
}, "Default Value");`

NOTE: Taken from [Alertify examples](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/)

Answer (score 0):

dont mix javascript(client) and php(server) directly,
 to pass data from client to server or server to client you can use ajax

Comment: To make an extra request instead of including the data that you already have is not efficient. Besides, this should be a comment, it doesn't address the actual question at all.

Comment: you are write,, but the data should be in sync, and should be understood by both client and server, the proper way is passing data in xml,json

Comment: What is the purpose of the server being able to understand data that it will never ever need to understand?

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt` method is asynchronous, so the callback will be called after you have exited the outer function. Submit the form from the callback:

```
alertify.prompt("New Amount of Item : ", function(e, str){
  if(e){
    completed = true; // note: no "var"
    var f = document.querySelector("#edit_<?= $row["item_id"]; ?>");
    document.querySelector("input[name=\"item_amount\"]", f).value = str;
    f.submit();
  }
})
```